# jQuery: fixed top menu like in Facebook and Twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to do this with jQuery?

I know how to do this with css (position:fixed), but IE problems (doesn't know about fixed position) worry me.

Maybe there is some plugin, but I didn't find it...

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this page: http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/ It'll allow you to just use CSS instead of having to use javascript.

Comment: You can do it purelly in `CSS` !! Just post your code to let us help you. :)

Answer (score 2):

`position: fixed;` is an alternative to `position: absolute; position: relative;` and `position: static;`. `position: fixed;` is basically the same as `position: absolute;` except that when the user scrolls the page, the element does not scroll with it, it just says exactly where it was

The problem is that the most popular browser - Internet Explorer for Windows - does not understand it, and instead of reverting to `position: absolute;` which would be better than nothing, it reverts to `position: static;` as specified by the CSS standard. This has the same effect as having no positioning at all. Note that IE 7 from beta 2 upwards does support `position: fixed;`

Some authors use the > CSS selector to isolate Internet Explorer and leave the element positioned absolutely in that browser, without the scrolling effect.

```
div#fixme { position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; }
body > div#fixme { position: fixed; }
```

or

```
div#fixme {
  left: expression( document.body.scrollLeft + 'px' );
  top: expression( document.body.scrollTop + 'px' );
}
body > div#fixme { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; }
```

I noticed something slightly odd. If I assigned the value to a variable, then used that to assign it to the expression inline, it did update in Internet Explorer 5.5 and 6. It is slightly jerky, but not as bad as many script driven positioning techniques.

```
top: expression( ( ignoreMe = document.body.scrollTop ) + 'px' );
ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop
```

or

```
<style type="text/css">
#fixme {
  /* Netscape 4, IE 4.x-5.0/Win and other lesser browsers will use this */
  position: absolute; right: 20px; bottom: 10px;
}
body > div#fixme {
  /* used by Opera 5+, Netscape6+/Mozilla, Konqueror, Safari, OmniWeb 4.5+, iCab, ICEbrowser */
  position: fixed;
}
</style>
<!--[if gte IE 5.5]>
<![if lt IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
div#fixme {
  /* IE5.5+/Win - this is more specific than the IE 5.0 version */
  right: auto; bottom: auto;
  left: expression( ( -20 - fixme.offsetWidth + ( document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : document.body.clientWidth ) + ( ignoreMe2 = document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft ) ) + 'px' );
  top: expression( ( -10 - fixme.offsetHeight + ( document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight ) + ( ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop ) ) + 'px' );
}
</style>
<![endif]>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a great article [here](http://ryanfait.com/resources/fixed-positioning-in-internet-explorer/) about css position fixed and how to accomplish this on IE6 and above. If you need any help with anything let me know.